# Connect two roscore's

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
i have two computers and each of them runnig roscore, is there any way to share topics between these two computers?
any help would be welcome

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200252/connect-two-roscore%27s/) by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-31**:
There are a number of solutions for this problem. Search for "multimaster"

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-12-31**:
Normal tcpip using python is not too hard to do either.

**Comment by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on 2015-01-01**:
Hi atp, i am not really good at that tcpip connection, can you advice me some good tutorial please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not clear from your question exactly what capability you require.

The easy case: ROS is a distributed system that supports topic sharing between computers out-of-the-box -- you simply need to use the `ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable (see the [Running ROS across multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) tutorial).

If you really need separate masters running on individual computers, follow the advice given by @ahendrix about "multimaster".

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0